# Find a word that only occurs once in a string

Tags: string, bash

How do I go about finding the one word that is not repeated in a string in `bash`? I'd like to know if there is a "native" `bash` way of doing this, or if I need to use another command line utility (like awk,sed,grep,...).

For instance, `var1="thrice once twice twice thrice";`. I need something that will split out the word 'once' since it only occurs once (i.e., no duplicates).

Comment: I would say no, there is no simple and elegant way. (I'm half prepared to be proven wrong, though. This site is amazing.)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath `var1` is going to be unused. I just need to somehow have the unique word, by itself, so I can use it in the rest of the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `sort`, `uniq` after splitting the string by whitespace:

```
tr ' ' '\n' <<< "$var1" | sort | uniq -u
```

This would produce `once` for your input.

(If the input contains punctuation, you might want to remove it before anything else in order to avoid unexpected results.)

Comment: that's exactly what I came up with :)

Comment: This is going to be used with a list of usernames, so no, there won't be punctuation.

Answer (score 2):

@devnull's answer is the better choice (both for simplicity and probably performance), but if you're looking for a **bash-only solution**:

**Caveats**:

- Uses **associative arrays**, which are only available in **bash 4 or higher**:
- Using a literal `*` in the input word list won't work (other glob-like strings are OK, however).
- Deals correctly with  multi-line input and input with multiple whitespace chars. between words.

```bsh
# Define the input word list.
# Bonus: multi-line input with multiple inter-word spaces.
var1=$'thrice   once twice twice thrice\ntwice again'

# Declare associative array.
declare -A wordCounts 

# Read all words and count the occurrence of each.
while read -r w; do
  [[ -n $w ]] && (( wordCounts[$w]+=1 ))
done <<<"${var1// /$'\n'}" # split input list into lines for easy parsing

# Output result.
# Note that the output list will NOT automatically be sorted, because the keys of an 
# associative array are not 'naturally sorted'; hence piping to `sort`.
echo "Words that only occur once in '$var1':"
echo "---"
for w in "${!wordCounts[@]}"; do
  (( wordCounts[$w] == 1 )) && echo "$w"
done | sort

# Expected output:
#   again
#   once
```

Comment: Agreed - stick with @devnull's solution and take this as a demonstration of bash's associative arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, awk:

```
awk '{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) c[$i]++
    for (word in c) if (c[word]==1) print word
}' <<< "$var1"
```

```
once
```

Comment: +1; easily generalized to handle _multi-line_ input: `awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) c[$i]++; } END { for (word in c) if (c[word]==1) print word }' <<< "$var1"`. One thing to note: list of output words won't be sorted.